# OpenCV not playing video using cv2

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am trying to load a video from my hard drive convert the video into grayscale and then play the video using opencv with python 2.7. My code is as below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap=cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/test/Desktop/Opencv/Crowded1.avi")

while (cap.isOpened()):
 ret, frame = cap.read()

 gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 cv2.imshow('gray',gray)

 if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Absolutley nothing happens at all when I run the file, I get zero errors but nothing pops up. Does anybody have any ideas on what I can do? I am following this tutorial https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html

Comment: What is `cap` immediately after it's assigned? Is your while loop being entered?

Comment: How would I check? Sorry I am really new to this

Comment: The loop runs `while (cap.isOpened())`, so maybe it never opens (i.e. doesn't find the file). Try printing `cap.isOpened()`.

Comment: Add a `print cap` after `cap` is assigned, and a `print 'here'` within your while loop so that you can see each iteration the loop runs.